# Error in opening PDF in Illustrator, circles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, import

I have a pdf graph that I create in R and I need to bring it into illustrator so I can compose it with other images, so I have saved it in PDF. When I open it on Preview, the image looks perfectly well and as it should.

[image: pdf opened in mac preview]

However, when I try to open it in illustrator note what happens to the circles:

[image: pdf opened with illustrator]

I have been diving deep into the different answers and tried different approaches with clipping masks but it did not solve the problem, the circles remain as crossed boxes.

Thanks in advance, any suggestions are welcome!!

Comment: What happens if you place the PDF (File -> Place) instead of opening it in Illustrator? If you do need to edit the PDF, you could try placing the PDF first and then flatten the PDF.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. These are missing glyphs, which suggests some kind of font substitution has happened because of a missing font.

Comment: @AndrewH thanks for your input, it worked. I tried what you suggested and once I flatten the pdf image it turns back into boxes, so I cannot edit. However it is ok, I really don't need editing that much, it was just because I wanted to try and move some vertices, separate them, but its ok, I'm trying to do it over the code in R. Thanks again!

Comment: @BillyKerr You are right, I changed the fonts from original source in R into Helvetica because I did not want any incompatibilities but it seems like it has indeed produced this problem.

Comment: Can't you export from R making sure fonts are embedded in the PDF, or alternatively turn these specific characters into outlines instead?  Sorry I have no experience with R so I can't help you there with any specifics.

Comment: It normally is embedded but this particular package does not  make the output this way, however I will check the options, this might be programmed, I'll check it out, thanks for the tip @BillyKerr!

Comment: @UnaiVicente When you flatten transparency, you would also have to make sure "Convert All Text to Outlines" is checked. See this question [How can I open a PDF in illustrator and convert text with a missing font into outlines](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60548/how-can-i-open-a-pdf-in-illustrator-and-convert-text-with-a-missing-font-into-ou). But you might want to check out Billy's suggestion first.

Comment: @AndrewH great, yeah you are right too, tried it again and it worked now. Thank you!!